# Enum switch via tuple

Tags: swift, swift3

I am missing synatax for tuple as a case for switch enum.

```
public protocol QueryType {
    var predicate: NSPredicate? { get }
    var sortDescriptors: [SortDescriptor] { get }
}

 public enum Query: QueryType {
        case id(Int)
        case owner(String)
        case isSent(Bool)

        public var predicate: NSPredicate? {

            switch self {
            case .id(let value):
                return NSPredicate(format: "id == %d", value)
            case (.owner(let value1), .isSent(let value2)):
                return NSPredicate(format: "owner == %@ AND isSent == %@", value1, NSNumber(booleanLiteral: value2)
            }
        }

        public var sortDescriptors: [SortDescriptor] {
            return [SortDescriptor(keyPath: "id")]
        }
    }
```

In case with two conditions I am getting an error: `"Tuple pattern cannot match values of the non-tuple type 'MyType.Query'"`

Is it even possible ?

**EDIT**

What about creating `case ownerIsSent(String, Bool)`, then in `switch` as a

```
case .ownerIsSent(let value1, let value2):
return NSPredicate(format: "owner == %@ AND isSent == %@", value1, NSNumber(booleanLiteral: value2))
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are `switch`ing on `self`, which is of type `Query` - not the tuple `(Query, Query)`.

Comment: @NicolasMiari Got ya!, So what i need is : switch(self, self) ?

Comment: I don't think that would work either; `self` can only be one of the possible cases. I don't think tuples is the way to go; perhaps you need to rethink your data type

Comment: @NicolasMiari Please look at the edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the edit would work. I'd rename stuff only:

e.g.

```
case id(Int)
case sentByOwner(String,Bool)
```

You want to use Query as a factory for predicates I guess!? 
Then ... I think you could do this

Comment: Or perhaps he can agreggate more than one case using an option set?

Comment: well if there is only a very limited number of combinations for a Query I'd not allow arbitrary combinations but it should work fine I agree

Answer (score 2):

That's impossible. You can switch only on **one** case simultaneously. Even `(self, self)` would switch on the same case.

A solution could be to add a case with two associated values for example

```
case id(Int)
case owner(String)
case isSent(Bool)
case ownerIsSent(String, Bool)
```